# How to draw circles with random colors in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, random, colors

I am using SURF algorithm to match two images with OpenCV. 
And I have got the keypioints.

Now I want to draw these keypoints with random colors circles.

I know how to draw a circle in OpenCV with the function cvCircle, but the color is fixed with `cvScalar(r,g,b)`.

I want the the color of the circle of a keypoint in a image is different to the circles near it.

The library function `cv::drawMatches()` in OpenCV have the effect I want. But I don't know how to realize it.

Does anyone who can tell me how to draw the circles.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Suppose you want to draw circles in different colors on `Mat image`. Here is a way to generate random colors:

```
RNG rng(12345);
Mat image = Mat::zeros(500, 500, CV_8UC3);     // change to the size of your image
for (int i = 0; i < circleNum; i++) {
    Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
    circle(image, center[i], radius[i], color, -1, 8, 0);
}
```

Comment: This is great. I would suggest using HSL or HSV color space to generate a color with saturation and/or intensity at max and then only changing the hue and/or value, then convert back to RGB. It will leave you with less greys.

Answer (score 4):

`cv::drawKeypoints(matOriginal, keyPoints, matOriginal);`

with this method it should be posible to draw your matches.

Answer (score 4):

Just generate a list of random numbers and then convert them to int otherwise it will give an error:
TypeError: Scalar value for argument 'color' is not numeric. so convert it to int and then function for circle.

```
color1 = (list(np.random.choice(range(256), size=3)))  
color =[int(color1[0]), int(color1[1]), int(color1[2])]  
cv.circle(img3, (x1,y1), 2,color,2)
```

put your image where you want to draw circles.